# Is $x=\frac{1}{2}$ the solution of this equation $\zeta(2)= 1+{{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{\cdots } $?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, riemann-zeta-function, irrational-numbers

I would like to study the irrationality of  ${{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{\cdots } $

for $x=\frac{1}{2} $ using the irrationality of $\zeta(2)$ .

Some computations in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex+%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex%5Ex++,x%3D0.5) show to me that :

$${{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{\cdots } $$ converge to $0.64...$ for $x=\frac{1}{2} $.

**My Question here is:** Is $x=\frac{1}{2}$ the solution of this equation  $\zeta(2)= 1+{{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{\cdots } $ and does ${{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{\cdots } $  irrational for  $x=\frac{1}{2}$ ?.

Comment: No, it should be ~0.641186 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(1%2F2)%5Ea+%3D+a. In particular, this is not $\zeta(2) -1 = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1$.

Comment: @Loic: I would rather say that it is the solution of $a=1/2^a$...

Comment: Yep, silly of me. Was thinking of iterated square roots... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

A solution of $a = 1/2^a$ is transcendental.  First note that $a$ is not an integer.  It can't be a non-integer rational, because $2^a$ for positive rational $a$ is an algebraic integer, and the only algebraic integers that are rational are the ordinary integers.  It can't be an irrational algebraic number by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on some of this...

I suppose it makes no sense unless $x$ is between 0 and 1.  And in this case...

Define $y =x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$.  Then we have $y= x^y$.  For any fixed $0<x<1$, this defines a unique positive value for $y$ (intermediate value theorem will imply $y$ is between 0 and 1).

So that's one way to define it in the range we want.  It seems to me that solving the above equation gives us:

$$x = e^{\log(y)/y} = y^{1/y}$$

or

$$ 1/x = (1/y) ^{1/y}.$$

This can be written in terms of the Lambert W function to give:

$$y = e^{-W(-\log(x))} = \dfrac{W(-\log(x))}{-\log(x)}.$$

We won't get more explicit than that.

But your situation is much easier since you already know $y$.  So your question is the same as "is $y= \zeta(2)-1$ a solution to $y^{1/y} = 1/2$."  (No.)